# Very Peculiar behavior when I vectorize fromJSON and apply to list of json

Tags: json, r

I have observe very Peculiar behavior when I vectorize  fromJSON (from jsonlite library).

Following is my code to convert fromJSON function to vectorize.

```
library(jsonlite)
vectorize_json = Vectorize(fromJSON)
```

Now, I applied same jsonlite function to my three list. One json list is small (35 observations), where second list is very large(122654 observations). First list is part of second list. Third list is custom build json list.

Custom build json list is as follows.

```
json_list_3 <- c('{"Active": "FALSE", "MARKED": [{"Name":"tom", "age": "23", "hight": "130"}, {"Name":"tim", "age": "25", "hight": "160"}], "date":{"today":"April", "day":"15"}}', '{"Active": "FALSE", "MARKED": [{"Name":"tom", "age": "23", "hight": "130"}, {"Name":"tim", "age": "25", "hight": "160"}], "date":{"today":"April", "day":"15"}}', '{"Active": "FALSE", "MARKED": [{"Name":"tom", "age": "23", "hight": "130"}, {"Name":"tim", "age": "25", "hight": "160"}], "date":{"today":"April", "day":"15"}}')
```

first and second list is contain much complex and large json which contains list and data frame within each json. json_list_1 has 35 observation. json_list_2 has 122654 observation)

```
parse_list_1 <- vectorize_json(json_list_1)
parse_list_2 <- vectorize_json(json_list_2)
parse_list_3 <- vectorize_json(json_list_3)
```

Now When I compare  variables information from Environments in Rstudio. 
I found following things.

parse_list_1 is matrix type, with value of large matrix(385 elements).
parse_list_2 is list type, with value of large matrix(122654 elements).
parse_list_3 is matrix type, with value of list of 9.

parse_list_2 is only list is works as I want. it has as same number of observation as original list. It maintains json as list. So, later I can access list as I want.

Where, parse_list_1 and parse_list_3 doesn't work as I want. Both list has all data I want. However, when I try to view them, they are shown as transpose. they don't have as list. All feature name (variable within json) is lost or I can't access using feature name.

What I am doing wrong ? I want to know why this peculiar behavior?
How can I get converted as list as access using feature name( example in json_list_3 is Active and MARKED).

I want to see following result on parse_list_3,

[image]

However, I am getting following result, And not able to use $

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Updated question, Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Great, that's helpful. OK so it's not surprising that you can't use `$` but you can still access elements by index. I get a result similar to what you showed as your expected / desired output by using `lapply(parse_list_3, fromJSON)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I want. However, it is close enough that I can modify my code to use it . Now I have to figure out which method provide faster result when I have 122k of observation. However, my question remain, why this peculiar behavior  is seen when we convert fromJSON function to vectorize

Comment: If it's too slow you can try a multicore lapply. The way to do that depends on your OS but you should be able to find some examples on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in output behavior is due to argument called **SIMPLIFY** in Vectorize. Default argument for SIMPLIFY is TRUE. Therefore, I believe, Vectorized function was able to convert small list into matrix. However, When it came to large list. It was not able to convert it into matrix. So, if we pass argument SIMPLIFY = FALSE in Vectorize function, then we can get same consistent result. Change in code looks like as follows:

```
vectorize_json = Vectorize(fromJSON, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```